# Somar Campo Time MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Caros, possuo uma tabela com uma coluna do tipo TIME, a qual armazena o horario trabalhado no dia, e estou tentando fazer a soma destes horarios ao final de um mês, porem sem sucesso.

Usei as seguintes query:

Query 1:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT((SELECT sum(TOTAL)  
FROM horario where PRESTADOR='NOME' 
and MONTH(data) = 1 and YEAR(data) = 2015), '%H:%i:%s') as total;
```

Resultado "null";

Query 2:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TOTAL))) AS total_horas
FROM horario where PRESTADOR='NOME' and MONTH(data) = 1 and YEAR(data) = 2015;
```

Resultado "6.14:24:00";

Query 3:

```
SELECT sum(TOTAL)  
FROM horario where PRESTADOR='NOME' 
and MONTH(data) = 1 and YEAR(data) = 2015;
```

Resultado: "1526400";
O resultado correto seria 158:24:00

Comment: O que exatamente você está armazenando no banco? Pode mostrar um trecho dos dados da sua base?

Comment: Ola, acabei de resolver o problema, mas no banco são armazenadas horas como exemplo "08:48:25". Usei o time_format para resolver o problema, deixando a query assim :"SELECT time_format(
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TOTAL  
 ) ) ),'%H:%i:%s') AS total_horas FROM horario where PRESTADOR='NOME' 
and MONTH(data) = 1 and YEAR(data) = 2015;"

Comment: Depois não se esqueça de responder a sua própria pergunta e marca-la como certa.

Comment: Mas você armazena horários pontuais ou um intervalo por dia? Pois se você for fazer a soma dos segundos vai chegar a um número diferente do total trabalhado.

Answer (score 6):

Caros, obrigado pela ajuda,consegui resolver o problema usando o time_format deixando a query assim:

```
SELECT time_format( SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TOTAL ) ) ),'%H:%i:%s') 
AS total_horas FROM horario where PRESTADOR='NOME' and MONTH(data) = 1 and YEAR(data) = 2015;
```

Comment: Nossa senhora, ajudariam muito desenvolvedores  simplificar isso ai, acredito que muitos que usam mysql algum momento precisem somar horas.